# Spring cloud config search-path alternative for JDBC

Tags: jdbc, spring-cloud-config

After reading the doc, I understood that search-path is only for git backend.

My app is currently a modulith : each root package reflects a bounded context.

We have an old table containing a lot (a lot) of parameters.

I would like to switch to Spring cloud config using JDBC Backend if possible and exposing multiple configurations (splitted configuration : one per context)to a single application (the modulith) : like search-paths

Is it possible ?

I didn't try yet but it's a bit like organizing the application properties files in the /config folder where each sub-folder (/config/boundedcontext1/application.yml)

thank you